# Как вывести url в консоль хрома полностью?

Tags: google-chrome, консоль, инструменты-разработчика

Как вывести набор ссылок в консоль полностью, чтобы можно было скопировать эти ссылки все вместе. К сожалению, хромиумы считают, что показывать всю ссылку не обязательно и в середине ставится многоточие, поэтому копирование ссылки возможно только из её контектсного меню, что означает поштучное копирование, а потому неприемлемо. Как вывести ссылку полностью?

Пример:

```
console.log("http://www.somesite.ru/and/some/very/long/file.path?maybe=with&different=parameters#and-other-information,%20and%20even%20longer%20and%20even%20longer%20and%20even%20longer")
http://www.somesite.ru/and/some/very/long/file.path?maybe=with&different=pa…rmation,%20and%20even%20longer%20and%20even%20longer%20and%20even%20longer
```

- Явное указание формата `%s` или `%o` не помогает.
- При использовании `console.dir` вместо `console.log` ссылки выводятся полностью, но переводы строк заменяются пробелами.

Comment: Эм. Консоль это не средство выведение данных для копирования. Пройдитесь яваскриптом по странице и пульните все необходимое в новый элемент.

Comment: @Etki, мне это для себя надо, а не как часть сайта. Я из консоли вызываю скрипт, он мне закрывает лишние вкладки и выводит их адреса.

Comment: Так это не влияет на то, что 99% остальных пользователей и самой концепции консоли выведение полного текста не нужно вообще. Это не тот инструмент.

Comment: @Etki, а что нужно? Почему браузер должен считать себя умнее всех и выводить не то, что я вывожу, а то, что ему захочется? Даже явное указание форматов `%s` или `%o` не помогает.

Comment: Почему вы думаете, что ваш кейс настолько важен, что консоль должна под него подстраиваться?

Comment: @Etki, не так. Почему инструмент, предназначенный для вывода любых данных, должен вместо их вывода как есть, сделать с ними какую-то магию и вывести результат? Я вывожу строку. Любую строку. Я даже явно говорю, что это строка. Почему я не должен увидеть эту строку как есть??? Кто вообще решил, что надо угадать, что в строке ссылка, да ещё и подрезать её под 150 символов? Полчему мне должны быть важны именно 150 символов? Не 200, не 100, но 20, а именно 150.

Comment: Понимаю вашу боль, но 99% остальных разработчиков не хотят видеть многостраничные документы в консоли полностью, если они туда случайно попали. Консоль выводит *репрезентацию* данных, а не сами данные, и нельзя ее воспринимать как терминал вывода. Это **не** терминал вывода.

Comment: @Etki, у консоли нет ограничения на объём текста, так что претензии к многостраничным документам я не понимаю. Попробуй сделать `console.log(document.body.innerHTML)` на этой странице - выведется вся разметка, но ссылки длиннее 150 символов в ней пострадают. И в каком же случае этим 99% разработчиков нужен именно результат "выводи всё что хочешь, но вот ссылке я тебе попорчу при выводе"??

Comment: for teh last time. Эта не та консоль, которая cmd и терминал. Она не предназначена и не обязана выводить текст. Если это кажется несправедливым, то обращаться надо в поддержку конкретного браузера/движка, потому что мы не умеем силой мысли править бинарники.

Answer (score 1):

Пока сделал так:

```
window.open().document.write("<plaintext>" + urls.join("\n"));
```

Но вообще, с консолью было бы удобнее.